# Checking snapping connection of polylines?

Tags: arcmap, topology, polyline-creation

I would like to find a method using ArcMap that could check if all polyline are snapping and connected.

I tried to create road network, but I can see this information.

[image]

I have multiple polyline, and I would like to know if there is any ArcGIS tool that could help me to get information, if each polyline are snapping and connected.

Comment: I think if you want assistance here, you'll need to post some existing code that you have tried. We like to have specific items to fix, instead of general requests for help. Do you have any Python you have tried, or a particular ArcMap tool that you are having trouble with? The more detail you provide the more chance someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Use topology rules for Dangles in a geodatabase feature dataset.  Don't reinvent the wheel in Python.

Comment: agree with Richard. Please see this tutorial on ArcGIS, geodatabase and topologies. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/topologies/creating-a-topology.htm You are looking to create a FeatureDataset in a GDB, add the line feature class as part of that dataset. Then using ArcCatalog/Catalog create a new topology class in the dataset and specify the lines as input. Just a matter of configuring the topology to check for Dangles. You will still be left with a lot of false positives (correctly unconnected ends of streets), but it is a start.